# How to enable TLSv1.3 in Apache2?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I am running Apache2 version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-04-25T11:38:24
```

I would like to enable TLSv1.3 but I get an error below in Apache2 if I put `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3` in the `ssl.conf` file:

```
# apachectl configtest

AH00526: Syntax error on line 79 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.3'
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Is it not possible to enable TLSv1.3 in Apache2 (yet)?

I know Nginx can do it, but this question aims at Apache2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLSv1.3 is not yet supported by Apache 2.4.

When it is supported by OpenSSL [(see info here)](https://openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/05/04/tlsv1.3), Apache 2.4 should have it too.

Answer (score 22):

### Debian Buster = TLSv1.3 supported

In Debian Buster (currently in testing), the TLSv1.3 is supported already.

The following information is dated to:

```
# date -I
```

**2019-02-24**

---

Apache2 version:

```
# apache2 -v
```

Server version: Apache/**2.4.38** (Debian)
Server built:   **2019-01-31**T20:54:05

---

### Where to enable

Globally in:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf
```

Locally in:

Your VirtualHost(s) located in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

---

### How to enable

To this date, the TLSv1.1 has been deprecated finally. So, you want only TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3.

To do that, put this line in the above-mentioned file:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
```

---

### Cipher suites

The cipher suites are now divided into 2 categories, that being `SSL` (below TLSv1.3) and `TLSv1.3`, you may want to use your own set of ciphers, take this only as an example:

```
SSLCipherSuite    TLSv1.3   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
SSLCipherSuite    SSL       ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

### Curves

One important note to the end:

There is one new curve you could / should enable: **X25519**.

You can do this for instance like this, again only example:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves X25519:secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1
```

---

### Example domain test on SSLLabs

> Experimental: This server supports TLS 1.3 (RFC 8446).

[image: TLSv1.3 enabled]

Comment: What about `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`?

Comment: @ChazyChaz I personally don't use the ChaChaPoly ciphers, which does not mean they're bad or anything like that, it's just I know little to none about them. But what will interest you more is a performance impact - AES is *insanely* fast due to CPU instructions [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) if available, that is.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Poly1305 performs better on processors lacking AES-NI. That does typically mean pre-2011 though, so yes definitely becoming less of a requirement, but does more positive than negative to have it available. Chrome knows this, and on my i7-920 machines it favours using CHACHA20_POLY1305 over AES_256_GCM when both ciphers are available. (I can test this on any CloudFlare fronted TLS site.)

Answer (score 13):

TLSv1.3 is now supported in Apache2 version 2.4.36 with OpenSSL 1.1.1 [Source](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.4.36/CHANGES).

Answer (score 3):

### Editor's Note

Beware, using a PPA might ruin your system, at least the future distribution upgrades, from my experience at least.

---

### If you are ready to take the risk...

You may use this PPA, this command adds it to your system without any hassle:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

At the time of this writing, the current version was:

```
$ apache2 -v

Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-10-28T15:27:08
```

TLSv1.3 is supported in that version.

To enable it globally for all VirtualHosts, locate your `ssl.conf` and set:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

Then restart Apache2 and it should be ready for a test, notably it on these sites:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/

**My example result = TLSv1.3 enabled**

[image: My example result = TLSv1.3 enabled]

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the update to OpenSSL 1.1.1 was not enough. Apache had to be [changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475291) as well. That change was [backported](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1845263) to version 2.4.29. Therefore, since Monday with [2.4.29-1ubuntu4.12](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/2.4.29-1ubuntu4.12), Ubuntu 18.04 LTS supports TLS 1.3 out of the box now. That was the configuration mentioned by the original poster.

TLS versions, cipher suites, and curves are still a hot debate as the recent TLS 1.0 deprecation on Stack Exchange [showed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8229299). [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh) 3.0 was quite happy with the defaults of Apache 2.4.29 and OpenSSL 1.1.1. Therefore, you should double-check if you not inadvertently disabled newer technologies like the curve X448 or TLS 1.3. For example, if you use `SSLProtocol -all`, you are disabling all upcoming protocol version. For example, if you use `SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves`, you are disabling all upcoming curves.

Consequently, I am not sure if it is a good idea to tweak those defaults once and then forget about them. Instead, for those who like to change the defaults, looking for a maintained configuration, I used the Mozilla [generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&config=old) as starting point. At the end of today—so double-check tomorrow—and thanks to the already mentioned way to configure the curves, I went for the [SSL_Conf_Cmd](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd_value_type.html) API completely:

```
SSLEngine on
#SSLOpenSSLConfCmd MinProtocol TLSv1 # commented because current default in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 # if you have the computing resources, consider not to tweak this
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd CipherString ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves X25519:secp256r1:secp384r1 # if you have the computing resources, consider not to tweak this
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Options ServerPreference,-SessionTicket
```

If you go for a dual ECDSA+RSA based certificate installation, for example ECC from Sectigo and RSA from RapidSSL, the above fulfills [Security Level 3](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html), still backward compatible even with very old clients.